# Ocultar control según el valor seleccionado de un p:selectOneMenu en un dialogo modal

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con las siguientes tecnologías:

- tomcat 8
- java 8
- primefaces 5.2.11

Tengo problemas para ocultar ciertos controles dependiendo del valor seleccionado de un SelectOneMenu dentro de un dialogo modal. La documentación de Primefaces muestra un ejemplo muy claro y sencillo sobre como actualizar la página en base al valor seleccionado del desplegable (aunque el contexto del ejemplo no se realiza dentro de un diálogo): http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<p:dialog
        header="Abrir Incidencia"
        id="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados"
        closable="false" closeOnEscape="false"
        width="1060" modal="true"
        widgetVar="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados">
    <h:outputText value="Tipo de incidencia"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="selIncidenciaTipoEstados"
        value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId}">
        <f:selectItems
            value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.listaIncidenciaTipos}"
            var="incidenciaTipo"
            itemLabel="#{incidenciaTipo.nombre}" itemValue="#{incidenciaTipo.id}"/>
                <p:ajax update="txtOperarioAfectado comboOperarioAfectado"
                        listener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.alCambiarTipoIncidencia}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:outputLabel
        id="txtOperarioAfectado"
        rendered="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId == 8}"
        value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId}"/>
    <p:autoComplete
        id="comboOperarioAfectado"
        completeMethod="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.autocompletarOperario}"
        rendered="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId == 8}"
        forceSelection="true"
        value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.operarioAfectadoSeleccionadoCodigo}"
        var="codigo" itemLabel="#{codigo}" itemValue="#{codigo}">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
            listener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.alCambiarOperario}"
            update="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados"/>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{codigo}"/>
            </p:column>
    </p:autoComplete>
</p:dialog>
```

Por otra parte, el evento de ajax:

```
public void alCambiarTipoIncidencia(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("dlgAbririncidenciaEstados");
}
```

Mi intención es que Primefaces renderice los controles `txtOperarioAfectado` y `comboOperarioAfectado` en base al valor seleccionado de `selIncidenciaTipoEstados`. Para probar su funcionamiento, al campo `txtOperarioAfectado` le he asignado el valor de `incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId`. Con el anterior fragmento de código dicho valor no se actualiza. Sin embargo, si elimino el atributo rendered del control `txtOperarioAfectado` el valor si que se actualiza lo cual me lleva a pensar que, al menos en la parte de servidor, cuando el valor de `incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId` es distinto a 8 no renderiza el control. Sin embargo en el cliente no lo oculta. Así que mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo ocultar los controles `txtOperarioAfectado` y `comboOperarioAfectado` cuando no se cumple la condición `monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId == 8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he encontrado la respuesta en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15811174/2131029). Tal como comenta @LuiggiMendoza:

> Lo que viene a decir BalusC es que no se puede re-renderizar un
>   componente que no ha sido renderizado cuando se creó la vista
>   rendered=false. "Para ello, hay que buscar la actualización del
>   componente que contiene a los controles que queremos ocultar" no es
>   cualquier componente, debes asegurarte que el componente que los
>   contiene, de lado de Java, extienda de NamingContainer como
>   `h:panelGroup`, `<h:dataTable>` o sus símiles en otros frameworks.

En mi caso, estaba intentando actualizar el dialogo directamente:

```
<p:ajax update="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados"
       listener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.alCambiarTipoIncidencia}"/>
```

En tal caso, la solución a mi problema es fácil, Simplemente hay que introducir un nuevo componente ('panelPrincipal') que es el que va a contener a los controles `txtOperarioAfectado` y `comboOperarioAfectado`. Finalmente así queda la solución:

```
<p:dialog
        header="Abrir Incidencia"
        id="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados"
        closable="false" closeOnEscape="false"
        width="1060" modal="true"
        widgetVar="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados">
    <p:panelGrid id="panelPrincipal" style="border: 0;height:280px;" columns="2" rendered="true">
        <h:outputText value="Tipo de incidencia"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="selIncidenciaTipoEstados"
            value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId}">
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.listaIncidenciaTipos}"
                var="incidenciaTipo"
                itemLabel="#{incidenciaTipo.nombre}" itemValue="#{incidenciaTipo.id}"/>
                    <p:ajax update="panelPrincipal"
                            listener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.alCambiarTipoIncidencia}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:outputLabel
            id="txtOperarioAfectado"
            rendered="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.mostrarComboOperarioAfectado}"
            value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.incidenciaTipoSeleccionadoId}"/>
        <p:autoComplete
            id="comboOperarioAfectado"
            completeMethod="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.autocompletarOperario}"
            rendered="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.mostrarComboOperarioAfectado}"
            forceSelection="true"
            value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.operarioAfectadoSeleccionadoCodigo}"
            var="codigo" itemLabel="#{codigo}" itemValue="#{codigo}">
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                listener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.abrirIncidenciaBean.alCambiarOperario}"
                update="dlgAbririncidenciaEstados"/>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{codigo}"/>
                </p:column>
        </p:autoComplete>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: "Básicamente lo que viene a decir es que no es posible actualizar a través de ajax un componente cuya renderización está condicionada" incorrecto. Lo que dice BalusC es que no se puede re-renderizar un componente que no ha sido renderizado cuando se creó la vista `rendered=false`. "Para ello, hay que buscar la actualización del componente que contiene a los controles que queremos ocultar" no es cualquier componente, debes asegurarte que el componente que los contiene, de lado de Java, extienda de `NamingContainer` como `<h:panelGroup>`, `<h:dataTable>` o sus símiles en otros frameworks.

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza. Cierto, corrijo el post.